# Find a continuous function that maps $(t_1, t_2) \in I \times I$ to $I$ that satisfies four conditions:

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Find a continuous function that maps $(t_1, t_2) \in I \times I$ to $I$ (where $I$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$) that satisfies four conditions:

$f(t_1,0) = t_1$

$f(t_1, 1)=  1$

$f(0, t_2) =  1$

$f(1, t_2) =  1$

or

$f(t_1,0) = t_1$

$f(t_1, 1)=  0$

$f(0, t_2) =  0$

$f(1, t_2) =  0$

Everything I've tried has failed so far at this, and they all fail at least at one condition.  As examples I've tried:  $(1-t_2)t_1 + t_2, (1-t_2)t_1$, which both fail at the third and fourth conditions, respectively.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is $I$? The unit interval? An arbitrary index set?

Comment: Unit interval, I'll edit it to include that.

Comment: Do you need it to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, but it would be interesting to see one that isn't continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function with this property, even if you do not assume continuity.

If $f$ satisfies the first four conditions, we must have $f(0,0)=0$ by the first condition and $f(0,0)=1$ by the third condition. This is a contradiction.

If $f$ satisfies the second four conditions, we must have $f(1,0)=1$ by the first condition and $f(1,0)=0$ by the fourth condition. Again, a contradiction.